# Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am using Winforms, and I am trying to copy a file from one location to another. If a file with the same name is already there, I want to overwrite it. But I get an error like "Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

I want to overwrite the file. What should I do?
I tried `File.copy` instead of `File.move`, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 7):

`File.Copy(source,destination,true)` will overwrite destination if permissions allow. See [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

have you tried `File.Copy(src, dest, true)`. This might help overwriting the existing file.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.
The destination should be the new filename, not the destination folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check the write permission is allowed for the folder contains the destination file.

Try the following:

System.IO.File.Copy(src, dst, true);

true if you want the existing file will be overwritten.

To change or set file permission [click here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419)